# Using grep to pull data from subscription-manager

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I'd like to retrieve certain pieces of information from the Red Hat subscription-manager.

I've ran a few commands but they're not giving me what I want:

```
subscription-manager list --consumed 2>/dev/null | \
  grep -e "SKU\|Contract\|Account\|Serial\|Pool ID\|System Type"
```

Where this retrieves the information fine, however within subscription manager there is a section where it lists REPOS where you're subscribed.

However as it's a 1-many relationship e.g.

```
Provides:    Red Hat Beta
             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host
             Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for x86_64
             Red Hat Enterprise Linux Atomic Host Beta
             ...
```

I can't do a search on this without it being a mess or can I?

Ideally to have it reiterate through the `Provides:` section listing all subscribed repos. Or would using `awk` or `sed` be better?

Comment: you need to include at least your required output from your sample inputs. ALSO, we're not going to code it for you, you need to show you best attempt at solving the problem. Please read [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: But yeah, Awk looks like a better tool than `grep` for anything remotely similar to this. Weird that `subscription-manager` itself doesn't provide an option to generate machine-readable output, in this day and age.

Comment: Either way - fixed it, bit of a hack but should be enough to work system wide.

Comment: Better put that as an answer which you could then accept, although I'd suggest waiting to see if there is a better answer. In particular I would expect your solution to only work as long as there is only a single 1-to-many field output by `subscription-manager`

Comment: As a side-note, do yourself a favour and use `-E`RE so that you won't need to escape all those meta-characters.

Comment: Yeah I'd be willing to accept what other options available too, cheers for the input.

Comment: Is there a blank line (or some other sentinel value) that terminates the section? If so, I'd use a `sed`.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a machine handy with it installed, but give this a try:

```
subscription-manager list --consumed 2>/dev/null |
  sed -En '/^Provides:\s+/,/^\s*$/p'
```

the `-En` says to use extended pattern matching, but don't print unless asked.

The `/^Provides:\s+/,/^\s*$/p` matches all lines from the start string to a blank line, and prints them.

If there's no following blank line, try

```
sed -En '/^Provides:\s+/,/^\w/{ /^[P ]/p }'
```

or maybe

```
sed -En '/^Provides:\s+/,/^\w/{ /^Provides: |^\s/p }'
```